# What is an example of proper usage of the libSVM library functions?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm, libsvm

I need to see some example code in java so that i can figure out the proper functioning of the various methods defined in the library.Also how to pass various necessary parameters. 
some of them are
svm_predict
svm_node
svm_problem etc.
I have done a lot of googling and i still haven't found something substantial. And the documentation for java is another major disappointment. please help me out!!
here is some code that i have written so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import libsvm.*;
import libsvm.svm_node;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class trial {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   svm temp = new svm();
   svm_model model;
   model = svm.svm_load_model("C:\\Users\\sidharth\\Desktop\\libsvm-3.18\\windows\\svm-        m.model");
   svm_problem prob = new svm_problem();
   prob.l = trial.countLines("C:\\Users\\sidharth\\Desktop\\libsvm-3.18\\windows\\svm-ml.test");
   prob.y = new double[prob.l];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<prob.l;i++)
   {
       prob.y[i]=0.0;
   }

   prob.x = new svm_node[prob.l][];


   temp.svm_predict(model, /*what to put here*/);







}
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
try {
    byte[] c = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    int readChars = 0;
    boolean empty = true;
    while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
        empty = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
            if (c[i] == '\n') {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
} finally {
    is.close();
}
}

}
```

I already have a model file created and i want to predict a sample data using this model file. I have given prob.y[] a label of 0 .
Any example code that has been written by you will be of great help.
P.S. I am supposed to make an SVM based POS tagger. that is why i have tagged nlp.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty straightforward.

For training you could write something of the form:

```
svm_train training = new svm_train(); 

String[] options = new String[7];
options [0] = "-c";
options [1] = "1";
options [2] = "-t";
options [3] = "0";     //linear kernel          
options [4] = "-v";
options [5] = "10";    //10 fold cross-validation
options [6] = your_training_filename;   

training.run(options);
```

If you choose to save the model. Then you can retrieve it by

```
libsvm.svm_model model = training.getModel();
```

If you wish to test the model on test data, you could write something of the form:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test_file));           
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(prediction_output_file)));     
svm_predict.predict(input, output, model, 0);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: the method svm_predict defined  in the svm class is as follows 
    `public static double svm_predict(svm_model s, svm_node[] svm_nds)`
how am i supposed to give four arguments instead of 2..?

Comment: Please look at line number 36 on :
https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/java/svm_predict.java

Comment: in the read me file that comes in the libsvm folder i have these three predicting methods and none of them is the same as what you suggested. Do i have to download and add this github source file on my own or is it in the libsvm package.?
`public static double svm_predict_values(svm_model model, svm_node[] x, double[] dec_values);
 public static double svm_predict(svm_model model, svm_node[] x);
 public static double svm_predict_probability(svm_model model, svm_node[] x, double[] prob_estimates);`

@chaitanya Shivade

Comment: @SidharthKamboj If you download the LibSVM package from [the official website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/#download) you will find the file svm_predict.java in the java folder. You are looking into all classes in the java/libsvm folder.